# Adding specific columns automatically while creating a new table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am creating new database and in each table I want to have few columns like:

```
CreatedBy, 
CreatedDate, 
ModifiedBy, 
ModifiedDate,
....
```

So if anyone create table; these columns should add automatically and no need to script these columns in create table T-SQL. Either I create via design from Management Studio or use script it should add these columns automatically.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use a trigger, which executes after each insert

Comment: @Nadeem_MK I think he means when creating tables. I'm not sure if it's possible...

Comment: rene. There are already posts available where stored proc is defined to add columns in existing tables but i'm talking about like default columns for each table when created.

Comment: Have a look at DDL triggers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fooedeced03-decd-44c3-8c74-2c02f801d3e7.aspx

Comment: Right Szymon; i'm talking while creating tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Try this dynamic query (automatically add columns to your tables):***

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + ']
    ADD 
          CreatedBy DATETIME
        , CreatedDate DATETIME
        , ModifiedBy DATETIME
        , ModifiedDate DATETIME;'
    FROM sys.objects o
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM sys.columns c
            WHERE o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                AND TYPE_NAME(c.system_type_id) = 'DATETIME'
                AND c.name IN ('CreatedBy', 'CreatedDate', 'ModifiedBy', 'ModifiedDate')
        )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

***Output:***

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test]
    ADD 
          CreatedBy DATETIME
        , CreatedDate DATETIME
        , ModifiedBy DATETIME
        , ModifiedDate DATETIME;
```

***Update with DDL trigger:***

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_TABLES
    ON DATABASE 
    AFTER CREATE_TABLE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME
    SELECT @TABLE_NAME = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'SYSNAME')

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + ']
        ADD 
              CreatedBy DATETIME
            , CreatedDate DATETIME
            , ModifiedBy DATETIME
            , ModifiedDate DATETIME;'
        FROM sys.objects o
        WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
            AND o.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TABLE_NAME)
            AND NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 
                FROM sys.columns c
                WHERE o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                    AND TYPE_NAME(c.system_type_id) = 'DATETIME'
                    AND c.name IN ('CreatedBy', 'CreatedDate', 'ModifiedBy', 'ModifiedDate')
            )
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

END
GO
```

Save new table in `SSMS` or any another similar product. After it just reopen your table -

[image: ttt]

Comment: Devart. Thanks for your response but as i already mentioned not for existing tables. These column should add automatically when i create new table.

Comment: Just create a new `DDL` trigger and put this query into trigger body.

Comment: Devart. I did but no results.

Comment: That is really great. Thanks Devart for your help. It works as I wanted. Solved.